# PHP Function that can return value from an array key a dynamic number of levels deep

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic

Using PHP, I would like to write a function that accomplishes what is shown by this pseudo code:

```
function return_value($input_string='array:subArray:arrayKey') 
{
    $segments = explode(':',$input_string);
    $array_depth = count(segments) - 1;

    //Now the bit I'm not sure about
    //I need to dynamically generate X number of square brackets to get the value
    //So that I'm left with the below:

    return $array[$subArray][$arrayKey];
}
```

Is the above possible? I'd really appreciate some pointer on how to acheive it.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why can't you use `serialize` or `json_encode`?

Comment: I am trying to build a globally available static config class, where I can retrieve values by using syntax similar to `config::get('db:server')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive function (or its iterative equivalent since it's tail recursion):

```
function return_value($array, $input_string) {
    $segments = explode(':',$input_string);

    // Can we go next step?
    if (!array_key_exists($segments[0], $array)) {
        return false; // cannot exist
    }

    // Yes, do so.
    $nextlevel = $array[$segments[0]];
    if (!is_array($nextlevel)) {
        if (1 == count($segments)) {
            // Found!
            return $nextlevel;
        }
        // We can return $nextlevel, which is an array. Or an error.
        return false; 
    }
    array_shift($segments);
    $nextsegments = implode(':', $segments);

    // We can also use tail recursion here, enclosing the whole kit and kaboodle
    // into a loop until $segments is empty.
    return return_value($nextlevel, $nextsegments);
}
```

## Passing one object

Let's say we want this to be an API and pass only a single string (please remember that HTTP has some method limitation in this, and you may need to POST the string instead of GET).

The string would need to contain *both* the array data *and* the "key" location. It's best if we send first the key and then the array:

```
function decodeJSONblob($input) {
    // Step 1: extract the key address. We do this is a dirty way,
    // exploiting the fact that a serialized array starts with
    // a:<NUMBEROFITEMS>:{ and there will be no "{" in the key address.
    $n = strpos($input, ':{');
    $items = explode(':', substr($input, 0, $n));
    // The last two items of $items will be "a" and "NUMBEROFITEMS"
    $ni = array_pop($items);
    if ("a" != ($a = array_pop($items))) {
        die("Something strange at offset $n, expecting 'a', found {$a}");
    }
    $array = unserialize("a:{$ni}:".substr($input, $n+1));

    while (!empty($items)) {
        $key = array_shift($items);
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
            // there is not this item in the array.
        }
        if (!is_array($array[$key])) {
            // Error.
        }
        $array = $array[$key];
     }
     return $array;
}

$arr = array(
    0 => array(
        'hello' => array( 
             'joe','jack',
             array('jill')
         )));

print decodeJSONblob("0:hello:1:" . serialize($arr));
print decodeJSONblob("0:hello:2:0" . serialize($arr));
```

returns

```
jack
jill
```

while asking for `0:hello:2:` would get you an array `{ 0: 'jill' }`.

Comment: This requires me to pass in an array AND a string, but I want to be able to pass in only a string. For example `return_value('array:subArray:arrayKey')`. Is there a way to adjust your function to accommodate this?

Comment: You would need the array to be global. How could the function access the array otherwise? Or you could send along the array AND the key sequence encoded in some way (e.g. serialized).

Answer (score 0):

you could use [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) and [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) to walk down to the level of said key.

```
function get_array_element($key, $array) 
{
  if(stripos(($key,':') !== FALSE) {
    $currentKey    = substr($key,0,stripos($key,':'));
    $remainingKeys = substr($key,stripos($key,':')+1);
    if(array_key_exists($currentKey,$array)) {
      return ($remainingKeys,$array[$currentKey]);
    }
    else {
      // handle error
      return null;
    }
  }
  elseif(array_key_exists($key,$array)) {
    return $array[$key];
  }
  else {
    //handle error
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive function like the following or a loop using references to array keys

```
<?php

function lookup($array,$lookup){
        if(!is_array($lookup)){
                $lookup=explode(":",$lookup);
        }
        $key = array_shift($lookup);
        if(!isset($array[$key])){
                //throw exception if key is not found so false values can also be looked up
                throw new Exception("Key does not exist");
        }else{
                $val = $array[$key];
                if(count($lookup)){
                        return lookup($val,$lookup);
                }
                return $val;
        }
}

$config = array(
        'db'=>array(
                'host'=>'localhost',
                'user'=>'user',
                'pass'=>'pass'
        ),
        'data'=>array(
                'test1'=>'test1',
                'test2'=>array(
                        'nested'=>'foo'
                )
        )

);


echo "Host: ".lookup($config,'db:host')."\n";
echo "User: ".lookup($config,'db:user')."\n";
echo "More levels: ".lookup($config,'data:test2:nested')."\n";
```

Output:

```
Host: localhost
User: user
More levels: foo
```